# how can i test this component with jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

first of all, sorry for my english, i am a spanish speaker from chile. I want to test this component with jasmine but i dont know how to code the spec.ts file to cover all the statements. may you help me please? i will really apreciate it.

the code is this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, inject, Inject, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
 
//external
import {Auth} from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import { Session } from 'src/app/domains/session';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-codigo-verificacion-clave',
  templateUrl: './codigo-verificacion-clave.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./codigo-verificacion-clave.component.css']
})
export class CodigoVerificacionClaveComponent implements OnInit {
  email: any;
  currentemail: any;
  currentpassword: string  = "";
  newpasswordchange: string = '';
  
  //constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private session: Session) {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.currentemail = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('param');
    
  }
 
 
 
 
  async changePasswordCognito(){
   
      try {
  
        var user = await Auth.signIn(this.currentemail.toString(), this.currentpassword.toString());        
        var tokens = user.signInUserSession;
  
        if (user.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {
          
          const { requiredAttributes } = user.challengeParam;
  
          Auth.completeNewPassword(
            user,               // the Cognito User Object
            this.newpasswordchange
        ).then(user => {
            // at this time the user is logged in if no MFA required
            
            alert('El cambio de contraseña ha sido satisfactorio!!!, You are logged in successfully!');
            this.router.navigate(['/home-express']);
          
            console.log(user);
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
          
        }else{
        
        if(tokens != null){  
          alert('You are logged in successfully!');
          this.router.navigate(['/home-express']);
        }else{
          alert('User Authentication failed!');
        }
  
      }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        alert('User Authentication failed!');
     
      }
    }
  }
```

in the spec.ts file i have this written, the automatic code from the proyect:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { CodigoVerificacionClaveComponent } from './codigo-verificacion-clave.component';

describe('CodigoVerificacionClaveComponent', () => {
  let component: CodigoVerificacionClaveComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CodigoVerificacionClaveComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CodigoVerificacionClaveComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CodigoVerificacionClaveComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Cristopher Caceres! According to our community guidelines, we ask people to show what they tried to do. Questions like "educate me to do unit tests" are not once the community can help with. Some online courses would be way better.

Comment: Please take a tour:  https://stackoverflow.com/tour. It would help you to get better help from SO community